# i don't get when meeting schedule in calendly webhook

Tags: calendly

I get this request in my webhook. there is no field which like which time meeting schedule. ( I have changed some private data )

```
{
  created_at: '2022-03-28T11:51:16.000000Z',
  created_by: 'https://api.calendly.com/users/AAAAAAAAAAA',
  event: 'invitee.created',
  payload: {
    cancel_url: 'https://calendly.com/cancellations/VVVVVVVV',
    created_at: '2022-03-28T11:51:16.669509Z',
    email: 'test@gmail.com',
    event: 'https://api.calendly.com/scheduled_events/AAAAAAA',
    first_name: null,
    last_name: null,
    name: 'test@gmail.com',
    new_invitee: null,
    old_invitee: null,
    payment: null,
    questions_and_answers: [],
    reschedule_url: 'https://calendly.com/reschedulings/BBBBBBBBB',
    rescheduled: false,
    status: 'active',
    text_reminder_number: null,
    timezone: 'Asia/Calcutta',
    tracking: {
      utm_campaign: null,
      utm_source: null,
      utm_medium: null,
      utm_content: null,
      utm_term: null,
      salesforce_uuid: null
    },
    updated_at: '2022-03-28T11:51:16.669509Z',
    uri: 'https://api.calendly.com/scheduled_events/BBBBB/invitees/AAAAAA'
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the event's start time you'll need to send a request to the event uri included in the webhook payload (https://api.calendly.com/scheduled_events/AAAAAAA). The response to this request will include a `start_time` value.

Comment: Thank you for your response. got it. need to call API from webhook.